# Is there a way to use/create a simple colorslider in a windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, colors, powerpoint

I need to include a colorpicker in a form in a powerpoint custom task pane. I want to be able to show a colorslider which shows the gradient going from 0 to highest saturation of a given color, with a draggable control to select the saturation from the slider (like the one in the ColorDialog form). Is there an existing implementation in the api/easily available alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996423.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996423.aspx#colorpicker_topic3

You can try to create color slider with the help of above links.

Comment: Please prefer including the relevant parts/snippets directly in your answer so that it can stand on its own (e.g. if the links become broken in the future) and use the links as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996423.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also codeplex has probably hundreds of similar controls

Comment: I need just the color slider. Neither of the two examples allow access to just the slider. The first one does not say where the slider comes from.

Comment: in the first link, there's a code sample with the source, just see how he does it, and also there are useful code samples in the article itself